# Access query that only displays fields that are null

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to create a select query in MS Access that queries a single table and outputs the names of only the fields that are null (in my case I am using yes/no fields, so it should display the names of the fields for each row that contain "no" values).

Does anyone know how/if this is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: @AVG I've tried adding the columns (in design view) that I would like to query and the one table that it is coming from, then selecting 'No' as the criteria for the first column, then 'No' in the 'or' fields for the rest of the columns I am querying. I only get the rows back for which the first column is 'No'

Comment: post the query in your question if you want answers. Also, Access does not store NULL values for Yes/No columns.

Comment: Also, 'No' is not the same as NULL.

Comment: Mike, if you really want help, you need to provide details. No one can tell what you have tried from what you posted.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to get null value fields here is an piece of code how you may achieve it

```
Select iif(Field1 IS NULL,'Stuff To Do On NULL value','Stuff To Do On Non-Null value') as val1 from Table1
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Field1=Null is not valid. It should be Field1 IS NULL.